How can I set the parameter info in PyCharm to display by lines?
For example, when I press "Ctrl" + "P" in my Pycharm, parameter info is not displayed by lines, but in another one can be displayed by lines.
The following pictures are parameter info of Method "TitleOpts" in "options.py" in package "pyecharts". The reference code is as follows, please place the cursor in the brackets after "TitleOpts", and then press "Ctrl" + "P" on the keyboard.
In my pycharm
In another one
from pyecharts.charts import Line
from pyecharts.options import TitleOpts

line = Line()
line.add_xaxis(["a", "b", "c"])
line.add_yaxis("y_name", [10, 50, 30])

line.set_global_opts(
    title_opts=TitleOpts()
)

line.render()

In "Settings-Editor-General-Code Completion-Parameter Info", I couldn't find the relevant option.After checking "Show full signatures", it still couldn't be displayed by lines.

Did you mean to use Ctrl + Q (for Quick Documentation) instead of Ctrl + P?
